# Touches Began not working with Swift 3.0 on Xcode 8.0 beta

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, touch, touchesbegan, swift3

I am making a game with swift 3.0 on Xcode 8.0 beta. In my GameScene I have this `touchBegan` function:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        let location = t.location(in: self)
        let nodeAtTouch = self.atPoint(location)
        let touchedSprite = nodeAtTouch as! SKSpriteNode
        print("Touch Detected")
        if touchedSprite is SKButton {
            print("Button Touched")
            touchedSprite.run(SKAction.resize(byWidth: 25, height: 25, duration: 0.25))
        }
    }
}
```

For some strange reason the print on line 6 doesn't print out when I touch the screen, therefore meaning that the touch is not being detected. Any ideas or fixes, is anybody else having this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either (a) the scene's `isUserInteractionEnabled` is `false`; (b) there's something on the scene that is consuming the touches before the scene can get them; (c) this scene is not being shown like you think it is; or (d) the `print` statement isn't working like you think it should (there are some beta issues with `print`). I'd suggest adding/updating `sceneDidLoad` and `print` both `frame` and `isUserInteractionEnabled` (which will confirm that the scene is loaded properly, that user interaction works, and that `print` is working properly).